# Bool Tools difference problems (multiple objects)

Tags: modifiers

I created 5 objects which I have joined into one, applied transforms, then attempted to use the Bool Tools difference to remove it from another object that currently has another difference applied, and I'm getting undesired results.

Following other questions about problems with the boolean in Blender, I've checked normals, checked faces, but must still be missing something.

Objects Pre-Bool Tools Difference:
[https://snickers.org/~davis/blender/objectspreboolean.jpeg](https://snickers.org/%7Edavis/blender/objectspreboolean.jpeg)

Results of Difference:
[https://snickers.org/~davis/blender/booleanresult.jpeg](https://snickers.org/%7Edavis/blender/booleanresult.jpeg)

Normals and Faces of Diamonds used for the difference:
[https://snickers.org/~davis/blender/dimondfacenormals.jpeg](https://snickers.org/%7Edavis/blender/dimondfacenormals.jpeg)

Normals and Faces of Star:
[https://snickers.org/~davis/blender/starfacenormals.jpg](https://snickers.org/%7Edavis/blender/starfacenormals.jpg)

Should I be using Bool Tools Difference on each diamond individually instead of join'n them together? My 3D background is *cough* from mid 90s POV-Ray so Boolean is my default thinking which I am attempting to un-learn.

Source File: [https://snickers.org/~davis/blender/start003.blend](https://snickers.org/%7Edavis/blender/start003.blend)

Edit: Blender Version 2.93.6 (2.93.6 2021-11-17) under Mac OS X Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired result?

[image]

Then delete both modifiers from Object Circle.005.
Next select 'Circle.005' as Object to second boolean modifier of Object Circle.003.

A red modifier icon means incorrect settings. This modifier will not work. Here I can't see any any advantage to handle the pieces individually. Merging them before boolean operations makes it easier. But maybe different names for the objects?